# In UIScrollview restrict a particular delegate from the uiscrollview delegate list

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, objective-c-blocks, uiscrollviewdelegate

From the list of available `UIScrollview` delegate list . I want to restrict a selective uiscrollview delegate function namely:

```
(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

I want to restrict it from calling by the compiler . can i accomplish this . Any suggestions & help are appreciated!!

Comment: why dont you just return a nil?

Comment: Are you using many scrollviews or just one?

Comment: I am including multiple scrollviews

Comment: You can use tag to detect which one calls the method and depending on the value of tag just return nil for required one

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously you can assign a `tag` to each of your `UIScrollViews` (or just the one you need), and then check for that specific tag, or you can compare the `UIScrollView` in your delegate methods to the one you are interested in.

With tags.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if(scrollView.tag == 100){
   //do something here
   return imgView;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comparing scrollViews.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if([myScrollView isEqual:scrollView]){
  //do something here
   return imgView;
}
return nil;

}
```